# Determine if matrices are diagonilizable without calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Can I determine if these matrices are are diagonilizable without any calculations?
I know I can determine it by calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but I am not sure if it can be done without the calculations. Thanks

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 && 1 && 1 \\
1 && -2 && 1 \\
1 && 1 && -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I think that this one can be diagonalized based on the theorem that any real symmetric matrix can be diagonalized (correct me if I'm wrong). But what about this one:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 && 0 && 1 \\
1 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 1 && 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Not without **any** calculations. It requires calculations to determine symmetricity for example.

Answer (score 1):

The second example is a permutation matrix. Every permutation matrix
is diagonalisable over $\Bbb C$, since each permutation matrix satisfies $A^m=I$ for some $m$, and $x^m-1=0$ has $m$ distinct roots over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: could you explain a bit more what $x^m - 1 = 0$ is? and is there a way to prove that $A^m = I$? I am still kind of confused.. thanks

Comment: @ivana14 In your example, $A^3=I$.